# Binding rich:pickList to a Set

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I need help on using `rich:pickList` bound to a Set, not a List. Let's say I'm using this structure (taken from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839893/how-to-populate-the-right-side-of-a-richfaces-picklist) on `rich:pickList`):

```
<rich:pickList value="#{bean.chosenRoles}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allRoles}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

Being `bean.chosenRoles` a `Set<T>` and `bean.allRoles` a `DataModel<T>`.

I tried adding a conversor (`util.convertSetToList(Set<T>`) from Set to List that I use when showing data:

```
<rich:pickList value="#{util.convertSetToList(bean.chosenRoles)}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allRoles}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

But then I get a NullPointerException.

```
Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectManyHelper.getConvertedValue(SelectManyHelper.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectManyRendererBase.getConvertedValue(SelectManyRendererBase.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTogglePanel.processValidators(AbstractTogglePanel.java:265)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at org.richfaces.context.PartialViewExecuteVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewExecuteVisitCallback.java:55)
    at org.richfaces.context.BaseExtendedVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(BaseExtendedVisitContext.java:321)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:354)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.executeComponents(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:237)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartialExecutePhase(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:217)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:196)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1170)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:459)
    at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:316)
    at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: try to see if it works with directly connected list (don't use any from/to set convectors)...

Comment: I have added a `List<T> chosenRules` to my entity class and it works fine. The problem is that the project uses eager fetching (Hibernate) so I must use a `Set<T>`attribute.

Comment: not sure about your `util.convertSetToList` , but try setting the `Set` into a `List` right after the population of the set and accessing the List directly from the `xhtml`

Comment: Yes, tried that and it works, but that's just a workaround. I think there's no way to bind `Set` to the `rich:pickList`.As it is impossible to work with `List` and eager fetching (and the app is VERY slow) I'm trying to convert the project to use lazy fetching. If you feel like, add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your `util.convertSetToList` , but try setting the `Set` into a `List` right after the population of the set and accessing the `List` directly from the xhtml

Also read this answer by **BalusC** [Displaying objects from a Set collection in Datatable JSF does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712593/617373) (wait for JSF 2.2)

Comment: Already read about JSF 2.2 and, pun intended, I'm eagerly waiting for it.