# Richfaces 4.5 picklist having duplicates on right side

Tags: jsf, richfaces, picklist

**Environment:**

Jboss 7.1.1.Final
JSF 2.2.6
Seam 2.3.1.Final
Richfaces 4.5.10.Final

**Issue:**

The rich:picklist populates the right hand side with duplicates during the second time load of a popup. Here are the steps to reproduce.

1. The popuppage with the rich:picklist is loaded by clicking on a link in a main page
2. The popup page loads with the rich:picklist populated with the right side and left side values
3. The values are added from left side of picklist to right side and the popup is saved.
4. Now when we reopen the popup the picklist has duplicate values on the right side

**XHTML Snippet:**

```
<rich:pickList id="AssignRole" value="#{staffResourceRolesTargetList}" sourceCaption="Roles" targetCaption="Assigned Roles" listHeight="120"
converter="#{org.jboss.seam.ui.EntityConverter}" orderable="false">
    <f:selectItems value="#{staffResourceRolesSourceList}"
        var="assignRoles" itemLabel="#{assignRoles.name}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{staffResourceRolesTargetList}"
        var="assignedRoles" itemLabel="#{assignedRoles.name}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

**Note:**

- I have overridden the hashcode and equals method in the entity used in the picklist
- I had to use two f:selectItems list inorder for the right side to prepopulate
- The source and target list are of the same entity collection

Please help me debug this. I have spent a lot of time and hope that someone can give me direction. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Have a look here, maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839893/how-to-populate-the-right-side-of-a-richfaces-picklist

Comment: I guess when you reopen the popup the target collection is not `clear()` and `Collection.add()` is called again.

Comment: Thank you Geinmachi and Mahendran for your responses. Will try these and post back my results.

Comment: I could not solve in the java side as the collection looks right just before the load of the popup. So I ended up hacking with jQuery and removed duplicates after the popup loaded. Hope it helps someone.